# Google Apps SSO with Office 365, error 800478A6

Tags: powershell, single-sign-on, office365, google-apps

I used the "Google Apps SSO Pre-configurations" in Google Apps Dashboard.

With Powershell I think/hope I correctly configured the Set-MsolDomainAuthentication params:

```
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'PC'
Connect-MsolService –Credential $cred
Write-Output "Connected"

$dom = “mydomain.com"
$uri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=C01nil70o"
$url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2?idpid=C01nil70o"
$logouturl = "https://accounts.google.com"

$cert = "MIIDdDCCAlygA…..PcDEQD0d7q8YceADzjXe"  

Set-MsolDomainAuthentication
  –DomainName $dom
  -FederationBrandName $dom
  -Authentication Federated -PassiveLogOnUri $uri
  -SigningCertificate $cert -IssuerUri $url -LogOffUri $logouturl
  -PreferredAuthenticationProtocol SAMLP
```

(w/ backticks in actual cmd-let)

When I access login.microsoftonline.com, I'm redirected to Google, I log in and am redirected to MS again but get an error "Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in. Please try again in a few minutes. If this doesn't work, you might want to contact your admin and report the following error: 800478A6."

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: did you have any luck solving this?

Comment: Nope, I contacted both Google & Microsoft but after spending too much time on this I gave up.